# How do I delete characters (that are not vowels) from a user inputted word?

Tags: c, arrays, ascii, computer-science

So I need to create a program that reads a user inputted word, takes out any non-vowel character (including symbols), and prints what is left. For example, if the input is "program's" then the output is "oa". This is what I have so far, but I am not sure how to replace the letters with nothing, I put ??? in place of where I think the replacement should be. I've spent all morning reading through my class's textbook and online forums, but I haven't found a solution. I'm still a beginner and I'm really trying to get a grasp of this. Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHARS 100
void modString(char[]);
int main()
{

    char word[MAX_CHARS+1];
    printf("Please enter your word: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    modString(word);
    printf("%s\n", word);

    return 0;

}
void modString(char string[])
{
    int index, letter;
    if(letter=='a' || letter=='e' || letter=='i' || letter=='o' || letter=='u' || letter=='A' || letter=='E' || letter=='I' || letter=='O' || letter=='U' || letter<'a' || letter>'z')
    {
        string[index]=string[index]-'a'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'e'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'i'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'o'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'u'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'A'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'E'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'I'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'O'+'???';
        string[index]=string[index]-'U'+'???';
        // I don't even know how to replace the symbols
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the C language, strings are an array of chars with fixed positions, thus you can't simply remove one of them. I suggest you create an output string, with it's own index, and seek the input string for characters that you want (vowel). If it finds you copy the char appointed by the input string's index  to the output string and increment output index, else do nothing. Something like this:

```c
void modString(char stringIn[], char stringOut[])
{
    int indexOut = 0;

//Create a loop for seek desired chars until the end of the string, signalized by a '\0' char.
    for(int indexIn=0; string[indexIn]!='\0'; indexIn++)
    {
        char letter = string[indexIn];

        if(letter=='a' || letter=='e' || letter=='i' || letter=='o' || letter=='u' || letter=='A' || letter=='E' || letter=='I' || letter=='O' || letter=='U' )
        {
            stringOut[indexOut++] = string[indexIn];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This made it way easier. However, I got an error that said `error: too few arguments to function 'modString'`. Do I switch word to one of the arrays when I pass it?

Comment: In the main routine, you need to add another vector as a second argument, the output string ;)